# How can I make my existing responsive navigation bar into a hamburger menu for smaller screens?

Tags: html, css, navigation, nav

I designed a responsive nav bar and I really like the styling so far. However, although it is responsive in nature, it does not create the hamburger menu when the resolution is minimized. Is there a way to add code to my existing navbar to create this effect (without losing my styling)? Apologies if my code is a little sloppy. Any help would be much appreciated.

[image]

```
<!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]> <html class="ie6 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>    <html class="ie7 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>    <html class="ie8 oldie"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--> <html class="">
<!--<![endif]-->
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="boilerplate.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="index.html" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]-->
<script src="respond.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css"/>
<style type="text/css">
body,td,th {
color: #CCC;
}
body {
background-image: url(images/bg-main.jpg);
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="feed">
<img src="images/bg-nav.png" class="trw" alt="header" longdesc="http://roguewarriorstc.com"> </div>
<div id="LayoutDiv1">
<div class="topnav" id="myTopnav">
<a href="#home" class="active">Home</a>
<a href="#about">About</a>
<a href="#contact">Online Dojo</a>
<a href="#tenshin">TenShin Aikido</a>
<a href="#tsaa">TSAA</a>
<a href="#events">Live Events</a>
<a href="#news">News</a>
<a href="#contact">Contact</a>
<a href="#forum">Forum</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" class="icon" onclick="myFunction()">&#9776;</a>
</div> 

</div>

</body>
</html>




@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */
/* Show in default resolution screen*/

/* Add a black background color to the top navigation */
#LayoutDiv1 {
max-width: 80%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
-moz-border-image: url(images/bg-main.jpg) 0;
}

.topnav {
border-radius: 10px;
background-image:url(images/bg-nav.jpg);
max-width: 100%;
text-align: center;
background-color: #333;
overflow: hidden;
border-style: solid; color:#666;
border-width: thin;

}

/* Style the links inside the navigation bar */
.topnav a {
float: left;
display: block;
font-weight: bold;
color: #f2f2f2;
text-align: center;
padding: 12px 16px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size: 13px;
}

/* Change the color of links on hover */
 .topnav a:hover {
background-color: #00C;
opacity: 0.6;
color: white;
}

/* Add an active class to highlight the current page */
.active {
background-color: #00C;
opacity: 0.6;
color: black;
}

/* Hide the link that should open and close the topnav on small screens */
.topnav .icon {
display: none;
} 

 img.trw
{
position: relative;
max-width: 70%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
padding-bottom: 0px;
}

.feed {
border-radius: 10px 10px 0px 0px;
background-image:url(images/bg-nav.jpg);

text-align: center;
font-color: #00C; 
font-weight:bold;
background-color: #333;
    overflow: hidden;
max-width: 70%;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
padding: 0px;
border-style: solid; color:#666;
border-bottom: none;
border-width: thin;
-moz-border-image: url(images/bg-h2.jpg) 0;
margin-top: 10px;

    }
```

Comment: You can try to learn css query

Comment: Welcome to SO. I took the liberty to slightly edit your question. I embedded the image and removed your intro, since greetings, thanks, personal introductions etc. are perceived to distract from the actual question.

Comment: Thanks. I did try to add a picture, but it said I didn't have enough posts to do it. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use CSS Media Queries and JavaScript to accomplish this.

**Using CSS (recommended):**

Create a media query in your CSS, it is a way to create a responsive CSS rule based on screen width.   See this article: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries, 
the section titled: 
*Creating complex media queries*

Here is a working code snippet for the CSS, hit run code snippet, then resize the width of your window until the nav-button divs disappear and the hamburger <div> appears.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    @media only screen and (min-width: 701px) {
      /* hide the hamburger */
      .hamburger {
        display: none;
      }
      /* show all the nav-buttons */
      .nav-button {
        display: block;
      }
    }
    /* if browser window is small (max-width) */
    
    @media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
      /* show everything with the hamburger class */
      .hamburger {
        display: block;
      }
      /* hide all the nav-buttons */
      .nav-button {
        display: none;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="hamburger">
    hamburger
  </div>

  <div class="nav-button">
    nav-button
  </div>

  <div class="nav-button">
    nav-button
  </div>

  <div class="nav-button">
    nav-button
  </div>

  <div class="nav-button">
    nav-button
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

**Using JavaScript:**

You want to use the window.matchMedia function: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia

```
if (window.matchMedia("(min-width: 400px)").matches) {
  // make all the navigation visible
  // hide the hamburger icon
} else {
  // show the hamburger icon
  // hide the navigation until someone presses the hamburger
}
```

Comment: Thanks Kyle. I will try the css first. In your code, what is the curly braces with 3 dots? Does that represent the hamburger, or is that a placeholder for more code?

Comment: @Lori, the "..." was just a placeholder, I added a more obvious version of the CSS.  I agree with you, I think CSS is the better way to go.

Comment: AHHH, thanks Kyle. I will add that to my code and hopefully it works. Do I have to add that anywhere specific, or can it be anywhere In the css document? Sorry, I am new to this. I appreciate your help very much so.

Comment: @Lori, actually I DO think that you need to put the CSS somewhere specific for it to work, I would do some research on media query because it is a large topic.  I usually google "MDN media query" because MDN is usually a very good site to learn from (that's just me though)

Comment: it did not work. I created a video capture to show you, but I don't know how to post it so that you can see it in action.

Comment: do I need to link the "@media" in my html document?

Comment: I'm sorry if I am being a pain :D

Comment: my code was broken, probably had something to do with the javascript comments inside the css code.  The new code snippet should work if you hit run snippet and start resizing the window

Comment: You have to run the code snippet in full screen mode